# Excel vba to lookup a cell value in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have numbers in column A. Column C has a smaller set of numbers. I want to create a macro that will start testing each value in C if it exists in A, starting with C3. If it exists, I want the macro to delete that value in C and shift up whatever left in column C so that I won't have empty cells in between the data (Note: I don't want to delete the whole row). Then the macro should continue testing the other cells in C until it finds an empty cell, where it should stop by then.

Please help me to write that code. I'm not an expert VBA.

Comment: You know, you don't need to be an expert in order to try something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KleanC()
Dim Kill As Range, A As Range, C As Range, r As Range
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, N As Long
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set A = Range("A:A")
Set C = Range("C3:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each r In C
    On Error Resume Next
    v = r.Value
    N = wf.Match(v, A, 0)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If Kill Is Nothing Then
            Set Kill = r
        Else
            Set Kill = Union(r, Kill)
        End If
    Else
        Err.Number = 0
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next r
If Kill Is Nothing Then
Else
    Kill.Delete (xlShiftUp)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are quite welcome!

Comment: You guys are so quick and talented! It only took a few minutes since I had typed the question to get the answer with the perfect code!

Comment: I would like to claim it is talent, but it is only an adaptation of some previously written code.

Comment: If the whole code above is to take place in Sheet1 (using code names here) and I wanted to execute the code from a button located in another sheet (sheet2). What will I need to change?

Comment: I added sheet1.select at the top of the code and then sheet2.select at the bottom so that it will go back to sheet2 after executing the code but I didn't like the blinking that happens there